# Are missing variables an important factor when considering instrumental variable analysis?

Tags: causality, missing-data, bias, instrumental-variables

I'm currently reading some papers that deal with the effects of education on health (smoking and obesity). Mostly they use an IV approach (college availability).
However in several analysis, only a handful of variables such as age and age^2 and regional factors are used. Somehow, intuitively I feel that certain variables are missing (such as income, family background, etc. ...) but no studies talk about these missing variables.

Do these variables matter less when considering IV analysis?

**Some references:**
The effect of higher education on Women's obesity and smoking: Evidence from college openings in Turkey (Baltagi, Flores-Lagunes, Karatas, 2023)
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0264999323000986

The causal effect of schooling on smoking behavior (Mary Silles, 2010)

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0272775715000801

Comment: I think the answers are at risk of being opinion-based.

Comment: Obviously, it is better to have the missing variable. If you don't have it, it's debatable whether an IV approach really adds much value in the analysis as compared to SEM with no latent variables, or even OLS controlling for the measured variables as confounders. The only IV exploited benefit is placing some bounds on the extent of possible confounding.

Comment: What do you mean by "have" these variables? It is one thing to have them recorded, one can still decide not to use them or include them in different ways in an analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If the instrumental variable is good, the other variables do not matter, but it sounds like this is not one of those cases.**

There is a famous [example](https://www.nber.org/papers/w4483) from economics, which sounds very similar to yours, where college proximity (growing up in an area with a four-year college nearby) was used as an instrument for years of education to estimate the effect of schooling on earnings later in life.

It has become popular (I think) becasue it was an early and clever example of a factor that was important for whether or not you went to college but which at first glance seemed otherwise unrelated to how much you earned in your 30s. However, it turns out that growing up close to a college is associated with a bunch of other factors that could influence your income (e.g., parents' education level, parents' income, race). It could have been these factors rather than college proximity (via education level) that was causing a higher income.

We could try to adjust for these factors, but if we don't have a good understanding of exactly why some people grew up close to a college and others did not, we might end up missing some important confounding factor. Therefore, using a (flawed) instrument might not be a big improvement over estimating the effect by OLS, adjusting for whatever confounders we can think of and measure; as AdamO wrote in his comment.

Assuming these cases are indeed similar (college availability = college proximity?), your intuition is correct. We certainly need to adjust for **at least** family background to make individuals who grew up near a college comparable to those who did not.

However, note that if the instrument had been as good as randomly assigned, there would have been no need to adjust for confounders. We would adjust for other variables only to reduce noise (to make the estimate more precise) or to demonstrate that adjustment did not matter (supporting the claim that the instrument was as good as random). If this were the case, we might not bother to make the list of variables exhaustive, or even properly motitvated, as long as they were all pre-treatment variables.